VIX vmrun not found
VIX vmrun not found. GNS3 can't find the vmware vm. It's installed. I'm on Ubuntu 22.02.
GNS3 was able to find and is working with the gns3 vm I installed on virtualbox, but gns3 advises against using virtualbox.
How can I get GNS3 to work with VMware workstation player?
I'm running 22.04.
Please advise.


